# TCPServer vs HTTPServer

Tags: python, httpserver, tcpserver

I am writing a simple python3 webserver. I have tried various tutorials and all work pretty well. Nevertheless there is a difference that I don't understand.

In one tutorial, they use HTTPServer as follows:

```
server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler) 
server.serve_forever()
```

In another tutorial, they use socketserver.TCPServer as follows:

```
with socketserver.TCPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler) as httpd:
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

**What is the difference between both methods?** All I need is a simple webserver that is able to receive JSON files through POSTs and aswer with another JSON. In both cases, I would use the same handler:

```
class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write("{dummy:'dummy'}")

    def do_POST(self):
        # Doesn't do anything with posted data for this example
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write("{dummy:'dummy'}")
```

**Does one of the methods suit my needs better? Is there an even better way of writing this server for my needs?**

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: `TCPServer` is more general, it can be used for any TCP protocol, you have to write the application code yourself. `HTTPServer` is specific to the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TCP is an **OSI Layer 4 transport protocol**, whereas HTTP is a **higher Layer 7 application protocol**, built on top of TCP.

In fact, it looks like `HTTPServer` inherits directly from `socketserver.TCPServer`, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html):

> One class, HTTPServer, is a socketserver.TCPServer subclass. It
>   creates and listens at the HTTP socket, dispatching the requests to a
>   handler.

For example, TCP will take care of establishing a connection (the three-way handshake with `SYN`, `SYN-ACK` and `ACK`) but it doesn't really prescribe much in terms of the structure of the data interaction (request/response). If you use the TCP protocol, you'll generally need to write all your own data processing code.

> All I need is a simple webserver that is able to receive JSON files
>   through POSTs and aswer with another JSON

This suggests the HTTP server is better suited for your need here, as the concept of a `POST`, and your description of an `answer with another JSON` is probably going to include a response (with a response body, response headers, and a response status). All of these will be HTTP concepts. As the documentation for `http.server. BaseHTTPRequestHandler` states, it will include an instance variable called `command` that is your request method (`GET`, for instance).

I can't tell exactly how `myhandler` is assigned in your example code, but looking at some of the other documentation examples, it looks like a `http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8000
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

A frequently pattern of instantiating work for a server appears to be

1. To instantiate a lower-level protocol server (ie. TCP) and pass in a higher level handler (like `http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`), hence the `socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), myhandler)`.
2. To use it within a context manager (`with` keyword), most likely because you need to tear down / deallocate resources after the server finishes execution.